# JAX-RS client/server application using JSON and Wink

Tags: json, rest, websphere, jax-rs, apache-wink

I'd like to implement JAX-RS server (on WebSphere Application Server) and client applications using JSON (Jackson convertor) format and Wink provider.

1. Do i need to use JAXB annotations for my DTO class that would be passed to and from the REST service and so must be serializable?
2. Which response type do i need to use, JSONObject or my Class type, i.e MyClass or String in Post methods negotiation between client/server?

In which cases we use JAXB annotations for domain classes in Rest services?

Your insight/directions would be high appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Erwin

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to read more about Jackson.
But here are some short answers:

1. For 90% of cases you don't need JAXB annotations on your classes at all.
2. You need to use your classes:

   @POST
   public MyClass myMethod(MyOtherClass mcls)
3. You use JAXB annotations for some complex mapping, when you are not satisfied with the default results.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer: it is often makes sense to use Jackson for JSON handling within Apache Wink. Jackson is more powerful and flexible than bundled facilities.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/wa-aj-jackson/index.html shows how to configure Apache Wink for Jackson.